# Is there any way to get only "-04" or the difference value based on whatever time zone is added in a query?

Tags: sql, database, timezone

Is there any way to get only "-04" or the difference value based on whatever time zone is added in a query?

```
select convert(datetime,GETDATE()) at time zone 'Eastern Standard Time'
    Result: 2017-09-12 17:49:18.377 -04:00
```

Comment: Please share your expected result.

Comment: I want "-04" from "2017-09-12 17:49:18.377 -04:00"

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Both convert and GETDATE are product specific functions.

Comment: Do note that it is only telling you what the local offset is at that *local* time.  Is that what you are expecting?  Maybe expand on what you intend to *do* with the result?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using sql server you can do this one of two ways depending on the data you want

`datepart(tz,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())` or `datename(tz,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())`.

if you take a look at these functions you will notice they require offsets. `GETDATE()` does not return the correct type. 
you will have to use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` instead.

for more information on this please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql)